# Can anyone tell me why my filtered array is empty?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar, searchbar

I have a table view and a search bar added to it (programmatically). I want to show the filtered results, so I've created an array(called: todoTitle) which contains titles for my todo activities (I have a separate object for them and one of its properties is title). I use updateSearchResults method and inside of it I use a filter method to return right todos. In order to check that the arrays aren't empty, I write code inside of that function to print the todos inside of each array. Here is my code inside of updateSearchResults(for:) function

```
    //filtering through todos' titles
    filteredTodos = self.todosTitle.filter({ (title: String) -> Bool in
        if title.lowercased().contains((self.searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased())!) {
            return true
        } else {
            print ("S \(todosTitle)")
            print ("t \(title)")
            print (filteredTodos)

            return false

        }
    })
    //updating the results TableView
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

``

todosTitle array isn't empty, so I don't understand why my filteredTodos is empty. Does anyone have any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: Printing the result array `filteredTodos` *inside the closure* does not make much sense.

Comment: you should print self.searchController.searchBar.text? to console and check. It is going to else block, that could be the reason.

Comment: `filteredTodos` won't be set with the result of filter until filter returns. just to be clear

Comment: Why is `self.searchController.searchBar.text?.lowercased()` surrounded by `()`? it's unnecessary and makes it look like a tuple.

Comment: @adev The problem occurs when the second table view should show the results of the search (error: unexpectedly found nil). It does so because its number of rows and the content of each cell is based on the content of filteredTodos array which is empty. I've tried to print self.searchController.searchBar.text? to console in else clause and it prints the letters until I press the letter which is inside my activities' title. In that case, it throws an error about nil.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ  I understand that. I don't understand why it doesn't return true. For example, in todosTitle array I have a running activity, so when I type r or R, it should return true, but it doesn't.
Parenthesis are set by swift because it says that I should force unwrap the text from searchBar. I can delete them if I change searchBar?.text to searchBar!.text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to check for if the todo item title contains the search text. Here's a simplified example that I tested with an array of strings and a search text string.  Perhaps separate out your assignment of the search text to ensure you're getting the string you expect from the searchBar.text

```
let todosTitle = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
let searchText = "t"

//filtering through todos' titles
let filteredTodos = todosTitle.filter({ (title: String) -> Bool in
    return title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
})

print(filteredTodos)  //["Two", "Three"]
```

Comment: I do the same, but instead of using some literal string, I use text from the searchBar. I checked, and in the method above my todosTitle array isn't empty, so other part of my code where I add some values to it, is just ok (I think so). The problem is, that I don't understand why filter method doesn't see that my todosTitle array isn't empty (again, print() function in the method above prints all objects that the array contains).

Comment: Even when I print "title" property from my closure, it prints all items in the todosTitle array, so it is not empty.

Comment: The filtered array won't be assigned until after the closure completes.